# Bookmarklet window.open blocked by most browsers, delicious/tumbler's does not

Tags: javascript, popup, bookmarklet

Hey guys --
The website I'm working on requires a bookmarklet launchable from your bookmark toolbar.
I've noticed that some browsers are blocking my bookmarklet.

However, similar bookmarklets such as Tumblr's, Twitter's, and Delicious' have workarounds where their bookmarklet pages are not getting blocked.

My current launch script looks like:

```
javascript:void(window.open(%22http://mywebsite.com/share/form?
            u=%22+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+%22
            &t=%22+encodeURIComponent(document.title),
            %xz%22,%22status=0,toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,resizable=false,scrollbars=false,height=379,width=379%22));
```

It's a simple window.open, which is clearly not enough to handle certain exceptions

The sites, below is Delicious' launch script, all seem to have workarounds that look very similar to that of below:

```
javascript:(function(){
f='http://www.delicious.com/save
?url='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+
'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)+
'&notes='+encodeURIComponent(''+(window.getSelection?window.getSelection():document.getSelection?document.getSelection():document.selection.createRange().text))+
'&v=6&';
a=function(){
    if(!window.open(f
    +'noui=1&jump=doclose','deliciousuiv6','location=yes,links=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,width=550,height=550'))
    location.href=f+'jump=yes'};
if(/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent))
    {setTimeout(a,0)}else{a()}})()
```

It seems like they append some extra GET parameters to the URL if the user agent is firefox.
I'm assuming then, if that is the case, that the init scripts on the actual page loading from the bookmarklet handles this exception somehow?

Has anyone had any experience with this issue? Would you be able to point me to any resources or tips? I have been stuck with this roadblock for sometime now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks -- I haven't seen all the controls on the site and I guess I'm coming off greedy. Getting at that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the delicious bookmark does not directly invoke the window.open() - it creates a function (called `a` in there) which is then executed in a `setTimeout(a,0)` for firefox (i assume the problem you have is in firefox).

You can try a similar method, and see if it works for you.

Comment: I had trouble testing becuase I couldn't get my prefernces to reset so i could get it blocked again.. I have taken notice of this but i didn't think that would make a difference. Ya think firefox overlooks the window.open direct call by embedding it within a function, within a timeout?

Comment: its the only real difference between those two snippets (other than the url+window parameters, which doesnt affect anything). To reset preferences, go to a commandline, and start firefox with the -p argument. That will allow you to choose a different profile, and so have a clean environment to test with : see http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing%20profiles#w_starting-the-profile-manager

Comment: dont run a windows pc anymore :P not sure how to do that on a mac

Comment: run the firefox-bin with the -P flag to start the profile manager